# IE6 positionning

Tags: internet-explorer-6

I have position the menu (left) relative to the wrapper
every browser display it properly EXCEPT ie6 for win, why ?

i try the -50% margin trick
i try the display inline trick
i try the all relative trick
i try the absolute trick

**Nothing seems to work**

HELP, any idea ?

[the link](http://www.acecrodeo.com/new/02-saviez-vous.php)

Comment: I am unable to load the link you gave.

Comment: copy paste it ????.. what the error you have

Comment: Just a thought, IE9 lets you emulate IE8 and IE7, but no IE6. What I mean, not even MS cares if the site looks horrible in IE6. What I do, I add a big message on top of the page saying (if you have ie6) "You are using a very outdated browser, please update to have a better experience". SOMEHOW WE HAVE TO MAKE THE USERS UPDATE THEIR BROWSER.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the reset css prop... I just add a good reset of the ul and everything is fine now ! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full explanation from [positioniseverything.net](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/doubled-margin.html)

in short, the solution is to add :   display: inline; to the css

in my case it work !... great !